# Steam library only some dlc and some not

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I bought civ v complete edition which includes all dlcs and expansion for civ v.     When I look in my library it only shows 2 of the dlcs and the normal coc games.  I still have the features from the other dlcs but I would just really like to actullay see them in my library when I open steam.  I geuss it doesn't matter but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the two DLCs you're referring to are the expansions, Gods & Kings and Brave New World. They're displaying because they're expansions rather than DLC. Most DLCs aren't usually listed in your library- it'd be pretty hard to find anything if they did!

If you want to view the DLCs you have for a game, right-click the game in your library and select "properties". Then click the DLC tab.

Comment: Not sure this is correct, with the new way Steam show "installed" DLC on the Game page in your library, which seems to be what the OP is talking about -- for Civ 5 I see all the scenario packs, etc. separately. I think it might be to do with how the game was bought (e.g. buy each item individually, or buy it all in a bundle?)